# 18.04 Task scheduler

Tags: 18.04, scheduler

I am trying to find the equivalent of the gnome task scheduler in Ubuntu 18.04 DESKTOP without success.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thx,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

It looks like GNOME schedule isn't being actively developed, although you can still get the [source code](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-schedule) and try building it yourself.

There are [some that suggest](https://www.hecticgeek.com/2015/11/when-task-scheduler-gnome-ubuntu/) using [GNOME when](https://github.com/almostearthling/when-command) is a good replacement for GNOME schedule.  The Github page contains both a .deb file and PPA that you can install from if you don't want to build from source.  When even has an alternative GUI if you don't like the current interface.

To install When from the PPA, do the following (from the [when instructions](https://github.com/almostearthling/when-command)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:franzg/when-command
sudo apt update   
sudo apt install when-command
```

Note: The update step should be unnecessary in 18.04, but it doesn't hurt to run it anyway.